# How to call PropertyChanged on Label for other property

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, label, propertychanged

Hello I was curious if it was possible to set `PropertyChanged` for a different property? My Label is bound to `Bandmember` and the text is bound to a property called `FormattedName`.

As this sits right now, it will only run this `PropertyChanged` event when the `FormattedName` property is changed. I have a different property called `Happiness` on `Bandmember` that I want this to call the `PropertyChanged` event for when `Happiness` is updated not `FormattedName`.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="dayView" ItemsSource="{Binding BandMembers}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="dayViewFormattedNameLabel" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding FormattedName}" PropertyChanged="DayViewFormattedNameLabel_PropertyChanged" />
                                <Picker Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Small" Title="{Binding FormattedName, StringFormat='Select Task For {0}'}" x:Name="TaskPickerInListView" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTasks}" SelectedItem="{Binding AssignedTask}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TaskDescription}" 
                                       SelectedIndexChanged="TaskPickerUpdated" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you control your `Bandmember` class? if so, you can raise more then 1 `PropertyChanged` event on change of `Happiness` property: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Happiness))); PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FormattedName)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found your new question (I see you realized why it was not working before)

I suggest using a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) instead.

What this will do is convert the int value of Happiness to a color, and you can then bind the `Label`'s `TextColor` property to `Happiness` using an `IntToColorConverter`, e.g.:

```
public class IntToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double percent = (double)((int)value) / 100;
        double resultRed = Color.Red.R + percent * (Color.Green.R - Color.Red.R);
        double resultGreen = Color.Red.G + percent * (Color.Green.G - Color.Red.G);
        double resultBlue = Color.Red.B + percent * (Color.Green.B - Color.Red.B);
        return new Color(resultRed, resultGreen, resultBlue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then to use it in XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IntToColorConverter x:Key="intToColor" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Label ... 
     TextColor="{Binding Happiness, Converter={StaticResource intToColor}}">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was way over complicating this.
Everything works perfectly now.